# How to find addresses and view stack in buffer overflow?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am learning buffer overflow and I'm stuck. For the basic examples with very few variables we could spam the stack and kinda overwrite the return address etc.

I am having difficulties examining the stack of a program. You can refer to the code below if needed.

My questions:

I'm using gdb-peda and I want to view the stack. Basically examine where the variables: `buf`, `byte_read1`, `byte_read2`, `idx1`, `idx2`, `idx` are and get their addresses.

1. I run `gdb ./exploit_overflow` and then `gdb start`, but when I type `p &buf` I can get the address of `buf`, but doing so for `p &idx1` & `p &byte_read1` does not work. Is this because the program has not gone into the bof function yet? But how come `p &buf` works?
2. If I would like to examine all those values in the stack for the `bof()` function how can I do so? I have tried: using **ni** to step and the **si** to enter the bof() and `p &buf`, `p &idx1`, `p &byte_read` works however when I type: `stack 30` and view the stack, I can't find the addresses of `buf`, `idx1`, `idx2`, `byte_read1`, `byte_read2` inside. Why is that so?
3. I have also tried `pdis bof` to view the bof function, but I am not sure how to find the return address. Is it the final line with 'ret'?

I hope my questions make sense and I am not looking for the bare answer and just trying to learn how I can examine the stack and find the relative positions of each variable etc. so that I can try to formulate an attack on my own.

Oh and I forgot to mention the goal is to run a shell in ./exploit_overflow outside of gdb.

Code (for your reference):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 64

char buf1[BUFSIZE], buf2[BUFSIZE];

void bof(FILE * fd1, FILE * fd2)
{
    int idx1, idx2, idx;
    int byte_read1, byte_read2;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    memset(buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
    byte_read1 = fread(buf1, 1, BUFSIZE, fd1);
    byte_read2 = fread(buf2, 1, BUFSIZE, fd2);

    buf1[BUFSIZE-1] = 0;
    buf2[BUFSIZE-1] = 0;

    if(byte_read1 != byte_read2)
    {
        printf("Reading different number of bytes from ./exploit1 and ./exploit2!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Buffer starts at: %p\n", buf);
    for(idx = 0; idx < byte_read1 + byte_read2; idx++)
    {
        idx1 = (idx % 2) ? BUFSIZE - 1 : idx / 2;
        idx2 = (idx % 2) ? idx / 2 : BUFSIZE - 1;
        buf[idx] = buf1[idx1] + buf2[idx2];
    }

}

int main(void)
{

    FILE *fd1, *fd2;

    fd1 = fopen("./exploit1", "r");
    fd2 = fopen("./exploit2", "r");

    if (!fd1 || !fd2)
        puts("Error opening ./exploit1 or ./exploit2");
    else
        bof(fd1, fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The goal is to run a shell in ./exploit_overflow

Comment: You should set breakpoints at relevant functions or code, otherwise those variables won't exist nor would it make sense to try and introspect them at start time.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Hi! Where do u suggest i set the breakpoint to get values for idx, byte_red etc.? I know I should look inside the bof() function. but do i put a breakpoint right before it returns so that i can capture the state of the stack after the buffer overflow attack?